# Summernote package cannot find jQuery using Webpack Encore

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack, summernote, webpack-encore

I'm trying to load package named `Summernote` using Webpack Encore (from Symfony), but on build I'm receiving error:

```
Module build failed: Module not found:
"./node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js" contains a reference to the file "jQuery".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.
```

I tried to fix it in methods like:

```
// webpack.config.js
.autoProvidejQuery()
```

and

```
// webpack.config.js
.autoProvideVariables({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'node_modules/jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

and

```
// main.js
var $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

Thanks for help.